How to yield only newly generated text
I have a Flask application that uses a RAG pipeline in the background, and I stream responses from vLLM. I'm currently using a function to parse and yield the streamed JSON responses. However, I'm facing an issue where the streaming output includes previously generated text, rather than just the most recent content
def parse_json_stream(line):
    decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(decoded_line):
        try:
            result, json_end = decoder.raw_decode(decoded_line[pos:])
            if "text" in result:
                print(result["text"]) # debugging
                if result["text"]:
                   yield result["text"][0].encode("utf-8")
            pos += json_end
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            # if can't decode JSON, go next character
            pos += 1

And here’s how I print the response in Flask using this function:
I want to ensure that only the most recent text from the LLM is yielded, excluding any previously generated text.
def generate():
    try:
        # We can use prompt_len to slice down the text, not using it right now
        prompt_len, response = process_and_respond(file_path, question)
        print("********* Generate Function **********")
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if line:
                generator = parse_json_stream(line)
                for parsed_text in generator:
                    if parsed_text:
                        yield parsed_text
    finally:
        print(f"Deleting File {file_path}")
        os.remove(file_path)


I'm not sure what is the payload you receive from process_and_respond, so I am just going to assume that the inclusion of the previously generated text happens inside this payload.
What you can try is to keep track of the texts you have yielded in parse_json_stream so you can compare it with the subsequent texts and return only those that have not been yielded before.
def parse_json_stream(line):
    decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0

    ### to track yielded text
    yielded_text = ''

    while pos < len(decoded_line):
        try:
            result, json_end = decoder.raw_decode(decoded_line[pos:])
            if "text" in result:
                print(result["text"]) # debugging
                if result["text"]:

                   ### remove yielded text from current text
                   to_yield = result["text"][0].encode("utf-8").replace(yielded_text, '')

                   yield to_yield

                   ### update yielded text
                   yielded_text += to_yield

            pos += json_end
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            # if can't decode JSON, go next character
            pos += 1


